# Is dynamic script execution order still unreliable in IE if files are loaded locally?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, dynamic-script-loading

If I load a number of JavaScript files dynamically using code such as:

```
element = document.createElement("script");
element.setAttribute("language", "javascript");
element.setAttribute("src", url);
```

then I understand that IE will load the files asynchronously and potentially execute them out of order.

If however my files are local, i.e. my URLs look like `'file:C:/myfiles/myscript.js'`, I don't seem to get any issues. Am I just being lucky because the files load quickly, or can I say that they are guaranteed to execute in order in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, script tags are synchronous, except if you added async attribute to the script tag.

That is why loading a script blocks the rendering of UI.

So, you can be reliable IMO.

Comment: Got any links on how to make a script async? Looks like a good trick to know

Comment: Script tags are, but afaik dynamically created ones are not